# Music ripped from CD not playing the original version from a disc on Google Play Music

Tags: google-play-music

I purchased a physical copy of SHINee's album "Lucifer" and ripped the CD to add it to Google Play. The CD itself plays the original version of the song "Lucifer," but every time I try to play it on Play Music, it plays a live recording. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Play Music attempts to match uploads against the (often higher quality) versions which Google already has obtained from the label/publisher.

On the Play Music website, in your Music Library section, right-click the songs and select "Fix incorrect match". Then re-upload the songs from your computer.

(Yes, I wish that worked.)